# How do i get Magnet links with Deluge or is it even possible?

Tags: deluge

They say it is not compatible any more? Why is the info hash button grayed out?

Does anybody know how do I get Magnet links with Deluge Web UI Client?

BTW, my Deluge Client Version is 1.3.5

Comment: Hi, this isn't Raspberry Pi related so I'm going to have to migrate you elsewhere. I hope that's okay.

Comment: @Jivings hello, well technically i was using RPi but i accessed it via SSH from my PC xD, i guess it's a general problem. no biggie :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109929/how-to-add-magnet-links-in-the-deluge-webui), magnet support in the WebUI was added in 1.3.4 back in May.  Are you sure you're up-to-date?

Comment: just edited a while ago, mine is 1.3.5, i don't know really whats happening but, try adding torrent files from kat.ph, it didn't work for me, even the magnet uri

Answer (score 4):

I right click on the magnet link and "Copy link address" or similar, and then copy that link into deluge in the "add torrent".

Comment: didn't work for me :(

Comment: It works for me, when I add torrent as an url, and I just paste the magnet link there.

Comment: I also found out you can drag and drop the magnet link onto the client.

Answer (score 3):

For the Mac, GitHub user [Lord-Kamina](https://github.com/Lord-Kamina) has written [Deluge-Magnet-Handler](https://github.com/Lord-Kamina/Deluge-Magnet-Handler), an AppleScript workaround. Installed in the Applications folder and run once to associate itself with `magnet:` links, those URL's should automatically open in Deluge thereafter.

```
on quit
    try
        tell application "System Events" to tell process "Deluge"
            activate
            set frontmost to true
            windows where title contains "Add Torrents"
            if result is not {} then perform action "AXRaise" of item 1 of result
        end tell
    end try
end quit

on open location this_URL
    try
        tell application "Finder" to set delugePath to POSIX path of (application file id "org.deluge" as string)
        set appExists to true
    on error
        set appExists to false
        display alert "Deluge.app must be installed in order to use this plug-in." as critical
        return
    end try
    set delugeArgument to quoted form of this_URL
    try
        tell application "Deluge" to activate
    end try
    do shell script (quoted form of (delugePath & "/Contents/MacOS/Deluge") & " add " & delugeArgument & "; return;")
    quit
end open location
tell application "Finder" to set thisPath to (POSIX path of (application file id "org.deluge.MagnetURIHandler" as string))
log thisPath
set lsToolRead to do shell script (quoted form of (thisPath & "/Contents/Resources/lstool") & " read url magnet")
if (lsToolRead contains "Magnet Handler.app") then
    display dialog "Magnet Handler is already the default application to handle magnet URIs" buttons {"OK"} with title "Notification" with icon POSIX file (thisPath & "/Contents/Resources/deluge_magnet.icns")
else
    try
        set dialogResult to display dialog "Magnet Handler has not been configured to handle magnet URIs.

Would you like to do this now?" buttons {"Yes", "No"} default button "Yes" cancel button "No" with title "Notification" with icon POSIX file (thisPath & "/Contents/Resources/deluge_magnet.icns")
    on error number -128
    end try
    try
        if button returned of dialogResult is "Yes" then
            do shell script (quoted form of (thisPath & "/Contents/Resources/lstool") & " write url magnet org.deluge.MagnetURIHandler")
            display dialog "Magnet Handler has now been configured as the default application to handle magnet URIs" buttons {"OK"} with title "Notification" with icon POSIX file (thisPath & "/Contents/Resources/deluge_magnet.icns")

        end if
    end try
end if
quit
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/525901)

Comment: Well, without blatantly copying the author's AppleScript code here, I'm not sure what you'd rather have me write? I think the essential info is there: Someone has written an AppleScript workaround that mitigates the problem for Mac users, and you may find it here, on GitHub, where he has chosen to host it.

Comment: This answer will be meaningless if the GitHub link is removed. You can always copy the code here, as long as you provide proper attribution. The code licence does not prevent this.

Comment: Done. I'm still not thrilled with this, though. The link contains a pre-wrapped AppleScript app that just needs to be downloaded, moved, and clicked. I feel like posting the entire code here leads a user into thinking that they have to actually fire up AppleScript and create their own app, which is actually unnecessary.